# 1987 Home Build: Multiple 14ga Switch Loops on 20 AMP Circuit

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker

I was upgrading some old light switches and noticed I had at least 2 switches using 14 gauge wire as the load leg for the ceiling lights. These were both on separate 20 AMP circuits.

I'm wondering if at one time this was allowable? The fixtures don't pull anything close to 15 amps, but from what I understand 14ga never has any business on a 20 amp breaker.

Is this okay / grandfathered in?

I'm sure the easiest fix is to pop a 15 amp breaker in my panel, which I can easily do if this type of switch loop wiring isn't allowed.

Comment: Do not know if it was ever allowed in the past, but don't think so.  14 gauge is not allowed on 20 amp circuits, so you have two choices, change the breakers(easy) or the wires(hard).  If only lights on the circuit, can go easy, if bathroom/kitchen outlets on the circuit, might need the hard choice.

Comment: No it was never OK. Either the builder did not get the memo, or *all* the wiring is #14 and some miscreant changed the breaker to 20A because of being sick of breaker trips.

Comment: Previous Homeowner was a miscreant, as you might remember from my previous post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Either it wasn't actually inspected, or someone "upgraded" the breakers after it was inspected.

14 AWG on 20A circuits was not allowed in 1987 (nor 1967), and it's not allowed now.

Comment: A brief poke into what the web will easily cough up says the basics of current ampacities were worked out in 1938 or so, and refined in the 1950s for multiple circuits, multiple ducts, and underground installations. But I'm not finding a simple archive of historical versions of table 310.16 or prior equivalent.

Comment: Good simple answer.  I had a similar surprise in my house when I found 18 ga wire in several switch boxes.  I can only imagine how that happened, and I'm certain it was never inspected.

Comment: I've seen some places like music practice rooms where the "light switch" was a circuit breaker.  I think the breaker also served outlets in the room, with the intention that if someone plugged in a device that drew too much current, power could be restored without having to visit the main panel.  Could such an approach be used in a situation like this?

Comment: Perhaps, but all the subpanel rules (such as working space) would apply to the "light switch" location, and it would probably be prohibitively expensive as a retrofit without a specific scenario like that to plan for. It would have to be a switching rated breaker, but those are common in the current era. However, given it's a switch loop, the energized starting point of the undersized wire is NOT at the switch, so **no.**

Answer (score 3):

For a circuit to be "grandfathered" in, it must have been in code when installed and not changed.

A circuit using NEMA 10-30 hot, hot, neutral(now banned) installed before the 90s can be grandfathered in(was allowed in code).  It should be replaced with NEMA 6s(hot, hot, ground) or 14s for your own safety

A circuit using 14 gauge in a 20 amp circuit installed in 87 cannot be grandfathered in, since it was never in code.